# Proof check: if $u_n$ and $v_n$ bounded, and $\lim u_n - v_n = 0$ then they have the same limit points.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

> Suppose that $(u_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(v_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ are bounded, and that $\lim u_n - v_n = 0$, show that they have same limit points.

So I did this:
We have $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N_1 \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $\forall n \geq N_1$, $|u_n - v_n| \leq \epsilon$

Let now $l \in \mathbb{R}$ be a limit point of $(u_n)$, then $\exists (\phi_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N_2 \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n > N_2, |u_{\phi _n} - l| < \epsilon$

Now, let $\epsilon > 0$, and let $N = \max (N_1, N_2)$ then $\forall n > N$, $|v_{\phi_n} - l| =  |v_{\phi_n} -u_{\phi _n} +u_{\phi _n}- l| \leq |v_{\phi_n} - u_{\phi _n}| +|u_{\phi _n}- l| \leq 2 \epsilon $. Thus a limit point of $u_n$ is a limit point of $v_n$. By symmetrical reasoning we prove that a limit point of $v_n$ is a limit point of $u_n$. Thus $u_n$ and $v_n$ have same limit points.

What worries in my proof is that I didn't use the hypothesis that both sequence are bounded. What did I miss?

Comment: Nothing. That hypothesis is not necessary.

Comment: @Hellen I think it might *technically* have to be there. We could have that $(u_n)$ and $(v_n)$ both diverge, so they don't have a limit point, but $\lim (u_n-v_n)$ is still zero. (But maybe that's fine, because if they each have no limit points, then they certainly have the same limit points). And on that note, at OP, when you take $l$ to be a limit point of $(u_n)$, how do you know that such an $l$ exists?

Comment: @MikePierce I guess I should then note that $l$ exists because both sequences are bounded. This is why I could proceed with the proof!

Comment: What if your sequences are given by the rules $u_n = \sin(n)$ and $v_n = \cos(n)$? These are bounded, but neither has a limit point. The sequences being bounded is not enough to give you a limit point. I think you need to exploit the convergence of the sequence $(u_n -v_n)$ more.

Comment: @MikePierce You don't need to know that the limit point exist. That is how assumptions work when you are proving an implication. You are only proving that if there is an element in the set of limit points of one sequence then that element is also in the one for the other. By the way, $\sin(n)$ and $\cos(n)$ have many limit points.

Comment: @Hellen, then maybe just for completeness, and for readers like me who would get hung up on something like this, there should be a sentence in the proof like, "*If neither $(u_n)$ nor $(v_n)$ have a limit point, they we are vacuously done. Otherwise, ...*"

Comment: @MikePierce Not needed, his proof is perfect as it is, but whatever makes you happy when you write your own proofs.